# Как создать запрос, который джойнит две таблицы, а потом выбирает только один результат?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Есть таблица статей и таблица пользователей в базе данных. Объединяем их с помощью JOIN, чтобы запрос показывал и статьи, и пользователей, которые их написали. Как теперь из этого запроса выбрать только одну конкретную статью, например, с id=1?

Comment: Если у вас проблема с двумя полями id в выборке, то нужно использовать алиасы таблиц:

    SELECT a.id, a.title, u.login
    FROM articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON a.author = u.id
    WHERE a.id = 15

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало, как я хотел)

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментария:*

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  u.login
FROM
  articles AS a
LEFT JOIN
  users AS u
ON
  a.author = u.id
WHERE
  a.id = 15
```